# How to change the icon of a QAction on a QToolBar when checked/unchecked?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtstylesheets, qtoolbar

I've created a `QToolBar`:

```cpp
QToolBar* pQToolbar = new QToolBar();
QAction* pAction = pQToolbar->addAction("CoordinateType");
pAction->setObjectName("CoordinateType");
pAction->setIcon(QIcon("global.png"));
pAction->setCheckable(true);
```

Then I tried to set the icon when checked in the stylesheet:

```css
#CoordinateType {
    image: url(global.png);
}

#CoordinateType:checked {
    image: url(local.png);
}
```

But it doesn't work.

So what should I do to change the icon when the tool button is checked?

Comment: What if to handle `toggled` signal of the action and change its icon in the corresponding slot depending on the checked state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Cause

There are a couple of problems with your approach:

1. You set the object name of the **action**. The action itself is not stylable. It is assigned to a **button** and its name is not transfered to this button (since a button might have several actions assigned to it). Thus your selector `#CoordinateType` won't work and you won't be able to target this particular button.
2. It is not possible to set the icon of a *QToolButton* using the *image* property, as the [stylesheet reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) states:

> The image that is drawn in the contents rectangle of a **subcontrol**.

If you want to set an image on a button, use `background-image` instead. Setting the following qss as a global stylesheet works to some extent, but again, it is difficult to target a particular button of *QToolBar*:

```
QToolButton {
    background-image: url(global.png);
}

QToolButton:checked {
    background-image: url(local.png);
}
```

## Solution

Considering the mentioned problems, my solution would be to use [QIcon::State](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#State-enum) instead of a stylesheet.

## Example

Here is an example of how to change your code to achieve that:

1. Create an icon and set it up

   ```
   QIcon icon;

   icon.addPixmap(QPixmap("global.png"), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::Off);
   icon.addPixmap(QPixmap("local.png"), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::On);
   ```
2. Set the icon as `pAction`'s icon

   ```
   pAction->setIcon(icon);
   ```

**Note:** It is possible, that you have to consider the other [modes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#Mode-enum) too.